# Pick random combination from 194481 possibilities

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, random

I have a file of 194481 permutations for
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,21

which looks like this;

```
[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,4],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,6],[0,0,0,7],[0,0,0,8],[0,0,0,9],[0,0,0,10],[0,0,0,11],[0,0,0,12],[0,0,0,13],[0,0,0,14],[0,0,0,15],[0,0,0,16],[0,0,0,17],[0,0,0,18],[0,0,0,19],[0,0,0,20],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,2],[0,0,1,3],[0,0,1,4],[0,0,1,5],[0,0,1,6],[0,0,1,7],[0,0,1,8],[0,0,1,9],[0,0,1,10],[0,0,1,11],[0,0,1,12],[0,0,1,13],[0,0,1,14],[0,0,1,15],[0,0,1,16],[0,0,1,17],[0,0,1,18],[0,0,1,19],[0,0,1,20],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,1],[0,0,2,2],[0,0,2,3],[0,0,2,4],[0,0,2,5],[0,0,2,6],[0,0,2,7],[0,0,2,8],[0,0,2,9],[0,0,2,10],[0,0,2,11],[0,0,2,12],[0,0,2,13],[0,0,2,14],[0,0,2,15],[0,0,2,16],[0,0,2,17],[0,0,2,18],[0,0,2,19],[0,0,2,20],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,3,1],[0,0,3,2],[0,0,3,3],[0,0,3,4],[0,0,3,5],[0,0,3,6],[0,0,3,7],[0,0,3,8],[0,0,3,9],[0,0,3,10],[0,0,3,11],[0,0,3,12],[0,0,3,13],[0,0,3,14],[0,0,3,15],[0,0,3,16],[0,0,3,17],[0,0,3,18],[0,0,3,19],[0,0,3,20],[0,0,4,0],[0,0,4,1],[0,0,4,2],[0,0,4,3],[0,0,4,4],[0,0,4,5],[0,0,4,6],[0,0,4,7],[0,0,4,8],[0,0,4,9],[0,0,4,10],[0,0,4,11],[0,0,4,12],[0,0,4,13],[0,0,4,14],[0,0,4,15],[0,0,4,16],[0,0,4,17],[0,0,4,18],[0,0,4,19],[0,0,4,20],[0,0,5,0],[0,0,5,1],[0,0,5,2],[0,0,5,3],[0,0,5,4],[0,0,5,5],[0,0,5,6],[0,0,5,7],[0,0,5,8],[0,0,5,9],[0,0,5,10],[0,0,5,11],[0,0,5,12],[0,0,5,13],[0,0,5,14],[0,0,5,15],[0,0,5,16],[0,0,5,17],[0,0,5,18],[0,0,5,19],[0,0,5,20],[0,0,6,0],[0,0,6,1],[0,0,6,2],[0,0,6,3],[0,0,6,4],[0,0,6,5],[0,0,6,6],[0,0,6,7],[0,0,6,8],[0,0,6,9],[0,0,6,10],[0,0,6,11],[0,0,6,12],[0,0,6,13],[0,0,6,14],[0,0,6,15],[0,0,6,16],[0,0,6,17],[0,0,6,18],[0,0,6,19],[0,0,6,20],[0,0,7,0],[0,0,7,1],[0,0,7,2],[0,0,7,3],[0,0,7,4],[0,0,7,5],[0,0,7,6],[0,0,7,7],[0,0,7,8],[0,0,7,9],[0,0,7,10],[0,0,7,11],[0,0,7,12],[0,0,7,13],[0,0,7,14],[0,0,7,15],[0,0,7,16],[0,0,7,17],[0,0,7,18],[0,0,7,19],[0,0,7,20],[0,0,8,0],[0,0,8,1],[0,0,8,2],[0,0,8,3],[0,0,8,4],[0,0,8,5],[0,0,8,6],[0,0,8,7],[0,0,8,8],[0,0,8,9],[0,0,8,10],[0,0,8,11],[0,0,8,12],[0,0,8,13],[0,0,8,14],[0,0,8,15],[0,0,8,16],[0,0,8,17],[0,0,8,18],[0,0,8,19],[0,0,8,20],[0,0,9,0],[0,0,9,1],[0,0,9,2],[0,0,9,3],[0,0,9,4],[0,0,9,5],[0,0,9,6],[0,0,9,7],[0,0,9,8],[0,0,9,9],[0,0,9,10],[0,0,9,11],[0,0,9,12],[0,0,9,13],[0,0,9,14],[0,0,9,15],[0,0,9,16],[0,0,9,17],[0,0,9,18],[0,0,9,19],[0,0,9,20],[0,0,10,0],[0,0,10,1],[0,0,10,2],[0,0,10,3],[0,0,10,4],[0,0,10,5],[0,0,10,6],[0,0,10,7],[0,0,10,8],[0,0,10,9],[0,0,10,10],[0,0,10,11],[0,0,10,12],[0,0,10,13],[0,0,10,14],[0,0,10,15],[0,0,10,16],[0,0,10,17],[0,0,10,18],[0,0,10,19],[0,0,10,20],[0,0,11,0],[0,0,11,1],[0,0,11,2],[0,0,11,3],[0,0,11,4],[0,0,11,5],[0,0,11,6],[0,0,11,7],[0,0,11,8],[0,0,11,9],[0,0,11,10],[0,0,11,11],[0,0,11,12],[0,0,11,13],[0,0,11,14],[0,0,11,15],[0,0,11,16],[0,0,11,17],[0,0,11,18],[0,0,11,19],[0,0,11,20],[0,0,12,0],[0,0,12,1],[0,0,12,2],[0,0,12,3],[0,0,12,4],[0,0,12,5],[0,0,12,6],[0,0,12,7],[0,0,12,8],[0,0,12,9],[0,0,12,10],[0,0,12,11],[0,0,12,12],[0,0,12,13],[0,0,12,14],[0,0,12,15],[0,0,12,16],[0,0,12,17],[0,0,12,18],[0,0,12,19],[0,0,12,20],[0,0,13,0],[0,0,13,1],[0,0,13,2],[0,0,13,3],[0,0,13,4],[0,0,13,5],[0,0,13,6],[0,0,13,7],[0,0,13,8],[0,0,13,9],[0,0,13,10],[0,0,13,11],[0,0,13,12],[0,0,13,13],[0,0,13,14],[0,0,13,15],[0,0,13,16],[0,0,13,17],[0,0,13,18],[0,0,13,19],[0,0,13,20],[0,0,14,0],[0,0,14,1],[0,0,14,2],[0,0,14,3],[0,0,14,4],[0,0,14,5],[0,0,14,6],[0,0,14,7],[0,0,14,8],[0,0,14,9],[0,0,14,10],[0,0,14,11],[0,0,14,12],[0,0,14,13],[0,0,14,14],[0,0,14,15],[0,0,14,16],[0,0,14,17],[0,0,14,18],[0,0,14,19],[0,0,14,20],[0,0,15,0],[0,0,15,1],[0,0,15,2],[0,0,15,3],[0,0,15,4],[0,0,15,5],[0,0,15,6],[0,0,15,7],[0,0,15,8],[0,0,15,9],[0,0,15,10],[0,0,15,11],[0,0,15,12],[0,0,15,13],[0,0,15,14],[0,0,15,15],[0,0,15,16],[0,0,15,17],[0,0,15,18],[0,0,15,19],[0,0,15,20],[0,0,16,0],[0,0,16,1],[0,0,16,2],[0,0,16,3],[0,0,16,4],[0,0,16,5],[0,0,16,6],[0,0,16,7],[0,0,16,8],[0,0,16,9],[0,0,16,10],[0,0,16,11],[0,0,16,12],[0,0,16,13],[0,0,16,14],[0,0,16,15],[0,0,16,16],[0,0,16,17],[0,0,16,18],[0,0,16,19],[0,0,16,20],[0,0,17,0],[0,0,17,1],[0,0,17,2],[0,0,17,3],[0,0,17,4],[0,0,17,5],[0,0,17,6],[0,0,17,7],[0,0,17,8],[0,0,17,9],[0,0,17,10],[0,0,17,11],[0,0,17,12],[0,0,17,13],[0,0,17,14],[0,0,17,15],[0,0,17,16],[0,0,17,17]... etc.
```

It ends at [20,20,20,20].

I need to pick 50 combinations from the file and assign it to a variable so it would be like

```
var combinationsArr = [
[0,0,17,9],[0,0,17,10],[0,0,17,11],[0,0,17,12]
]; //BUT 50 of them
```

it's okay if it is just in order like `[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,4],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,6],[0,0,0,7],[0,0,0,8],[0,0,0,9],[0,0,0,10],[0,0,0,11],[0,0,0,12]` and doesn't have to be super random like `[1,2,3,4],[9,12,13,15],[20,12,6,7]`

as long as it is able to pick 50 of them.

I am doing this because 194481 combinations are a lot and makes my program carsh. so I just decided i'll put it in a text file and pick random points from the text file like from [0,0,0,1] to [0,0,0,50] OR
from [0,1,0,0] to [0,1,0,49] if that's possible.

because i have to generate a random combination. I have another array of combinations which are not supposed to be generated. Let's call it notAllowedArr.

```
var notAllowedArr = [
[0,0,17,9],[0,0,17,12]
];
```

I am thinking, i'll just generate 50 combinations and remove the ones listed in notAllowedArr then pick one from combinationsArr as the final result. I will still have to find code to remove those from combinationsArr but the result should be like.

```
var combinationsArr = [[0,0,17,10],[0,0,17,11]];
```

then i'll have a code to pick a random value from combinationsArr.
example. combinationsArr[0].

so the final result would be; `[0,0,17,10]`

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Your program won't crash if you read it one line at a time:

    `var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream('permutations.txt')
    });
    
    lineReader.on('line', function (lineOfPermutations) {
      console.log('Line from file:', lineOfPermutations);
    });`

With this you can easily get the random permutations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to pick one random combination, which is not present in a list of forbidden combinations.

You can consider a combination of four numbers from 0 to 20 as a number from 0 to 194480 in base-21 notation. So instead of having to store all combinations in a file, we just pick a random number and convert it to base-21.

To choose a random number in a range where some values are forbidden, choose a number in the range from 0 to the maximum minus the number of forbidden values; then iterate over the forbidden values from small to large, and increment the random number every time you find a smaller or equal forbidden value.

This will make sure that every combination has the same probability of being chosen, and avoids the possibility of repeatedly choosing a forbidden combination.

```js
function randomBase21(skip) {
    var dec = [], result = [], num;
    // CONVERT FORBIDDEN COMBINATIONS FROM BASE-21 TO DECIMAL AND SORT
    for (var i = 0; i < skip.length; i++) {
        dec[i] = skip[i][0] * 9261 + skip[i][1] * 441 + skip[i][2] * 21 + skip[i][3];
    }
    dec.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    // GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER FROM 0 TO MAX - NUMBER OF FORBIDDEN COMBINATIONS
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (194481 - skip.length));
    // INCREMENT RANDOM NUMBER FOR EVERY SMALLER FORBIDDEN COMBINATION
    for (var i = 0; i < skip.length && num >= dec[i]; i++) {
        ++num;
    }
    // CONVERT RANDOM NUMBER TO FOUR BASE-21 DIGITS
    for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--, num /= 21) {
        result[i] = Math.floor(num % 21);
    }
    return result;
}

var notAllowed = [[0,0,17,9],[0,0,17,12],[20,19,17,12],[15,16,17,12]];
document.write(randomBase21(notAllowed));
```

Comment: Wow.. This is awesome. I'll use this. Thank you :D

Comment: @JohannaCristineDy Btw, if the list of forbidden combinations is fixed, you could sort it from small to large beforehand, and skip the sorting in this function. You could also convert the forbidden combinations to decimal beforehand, to make this function even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (off the top of my head and not tested/debugged):

```
var samples = new Array();

for(var index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
    samples.push(generatePermutation());
}

function generatePermutation() {
    var result = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1,
                  Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1,
                  Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1,
                  Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1];
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. I think i will do this then check the generated value if it exists in notAlloweArr. if it does, i will generatePermutation() again.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a better way.
I think I will make a function that generates a random combination.

Then check if it exists in notAllowedArr. If it exists, it will generate another one. If not then that will return that combination :D

I think this will work faster ^^;

Comment: If you need each combination to be unique, you can collate the combinations by their sums, i.e. [0,0,0,1] is 1, [0,2,0,0] is 2. Then when you want to check if it is already generated, you just first check if the sum exist then check already generated combinations from there. It will be faster than checking all the generated results each time.

Comment: @yoneal: [2,2,2,2] has the same sum as [0,8,0,0]

Comment: @SamAxe: yeah, so you would check only the subset of results with the same sum other than the whole set of results.